# Bootstrap Theme Not Being Applied

Tags: ngx-datatable

I'm trying to apply the Bootstrap theme to my datatable. I'm using `ngx-datatable` version 10.4.0 because I'm still on Angular 4 and 11.0 isn't compatible. According to the changelog, the Bootstrap theme was added in version 10.3.0.

Below is my component.html:

```
<div>
    <ngx-datatable class="bootstrap" [rows]="rows" [columns]="columns" (select)='onSelect($event)' [selected]="selected" [selectionType]="'single'"
        [limit]="10" [columnMode]="'force'" [headerHeight]="40" [footerHeight]="40" [rowHeight]="'auto'">
    </ngx-datatable>
</div>
```

However, this doesn't add the styling as in the [demo](http://swimlane.github.io/ngx-datatable/#bootstrap). I think I have included everything the [documentation](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/blob/master/demo/basic/bootstrap.component.ts) shows.

I'm using Bootstrap 3.3.7. Is 4.0 required? Am I not including something correctly?

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you are including the [scss file](https://github.com/swimlane/ngx-datatable/blob/master/src/themes/bootstrap.scss) to your build.

In `.angular-cli.json` you should add it:

```
"apps": [
  {
    ...
    "styles": [
      ...
      "../node_modules/@swimlane/ngx-datatable/release/themes/bootstrap.css",
      ...
    ],
```

also the `<ngx-datatable>` element should have both `bootstrap` and `ngx-datatable` classes:

```
<ngx-datatable class="bootstrap ngx-datatable">
```

Comment: I'm using ASP.NET Core and JavaScriptServices (https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices). I'm not sure how I can incorporate your answer as I don't have a `.angular-cli.json` file.

Comment: then include the css file as you normally would with that setup